# Change of field label in page layout using VF

Tags: visualforce

If the record is of a certain record type, I wish for the name, in this case "Service Name" to be displayed as "Project Name" instead. Because "Service Name" is a required field on every record, I think it's best to create a basic visualforce page that  displays "Service Name" as "Project Name".

We have 7 record types, and page layouts to match. How would we keep the existing 6 page layouts, and use only one visualforce page? I've seen somebody suggest using apex:detail, would somebody be able to provide me of a high level view of what the code should look like please?

At the moment I have the code below, but I wonder if it's best to start again down the apex detail route.

I'm struggling to understand how I reference my regular page layouts in this code, or if that's required at all.

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="R&D Project Edit" subtitle="New R&D Project" />  
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock 
            rendered="{!Product2.recordType.DeveloperName == 'Unavailable_R_D_Project'}">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
                showHeader="true" title="R&D Project Detail" >
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Name}" label="Project Name" / >
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.R_D_Directorate__c}"/>              
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Status__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Next_Stage_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.R_D_Unique_ID__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Lifecycle_Status__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Project_Owner__c}"/>
                <br/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Alternative_Project_Contact__c}"/>
                <br/>
                <apex:inputField 
                    Value="{!Product2.Can_the_project_be_discussed_externally__c}"/>
                <br/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Looking_for_participants__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
                showHeader="true" title="Description Information">
                 <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Project_Description__c}"/>
                 <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Cluster_Area_Portfolio__c}"/>
                 <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Benefits_to_the_customer__c}"/>
                 <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Eligibility__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
                showHeader="true" title="Service Information">
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Risks__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Include_in_Dashboard__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Service__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Sector__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Alpha__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Jisc_directorate__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Beta__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
                showHeader="true" title="Progress Information">
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Level_of_Demand__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Feasibility__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Notes_on_current_progress__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_usefulness__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" 
                title="System Information">
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.createdbyId}"/>
                <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.lastmodifiedbyId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you open to using Js/jQuery?

Comment: yes, i'm a novice at all of this, but will give anything a try!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by using custom `Visualforce` instead of a `Page Layout`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson to display "Project Name" instead of "Service Name" on records of a certain record type without creating a new field called "Project Name". How would you do that?

Comment: Are you trying to do so for just the `View` or also the `Edit`?

Comment: both @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.
I am just changing the label of 1 input field from hi to bye

```
public class product2_ext {

public List<RecordType> recordTypeObj; 
public List<String> recordTypeValue{get;set;}


public product2_ext(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

    recordTypeObj = new List<RecordType>([SELECT DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Product2']);
    recordTypeValue = new List<String>();
    for (RecordType rt: recordTypeObj) {
        recordTypeValue.add(rt.DeveloperName);
    }

}
```

}

And The VF that I used (modified)

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2" extensions="product2_ext">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        //alert(encodeURI("{!recordTypeValue[1]}"));
        //console.log('product2_record_type1' + "{!recordTypeValue}");
        alert($j.inArray('xxx',"{!recordTypeValue}"));
        if($j.inArray('ct',"{!recordTypeValue}") > -1) {
                                $j("[for$='thefield']").text("bye");
                             }
                        }
        );
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="R&D Project Edit" subtitle="New R&D Project" />  
<apex:form >
    <!--apex:pageBlock 
        rendered="{!Product2.recordType.DeveloperName == 'Unavailable_R_D_Project'}"-->
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
            showHeader="true" title="R&D Project Detail" >

            <apex:inputField id="thefield" Value="{!Product2.Name}" label="hi" / >
            <!--apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.R_D_Directorate__c}"/>              
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Next_Stage_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.R_D_Unique_ID__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Lifecycle_Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Project_Owner__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Alternative_Project_Contact__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputField 
                Value="{!Product2.Can_the_project_be_discussed_externally__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Looking_for_participants__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
            showHeader="true" title="Description Information">
             <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Project_Description__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Cluster_Area_Portfolio__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Benefits_to_the_customer__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Eligibility__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
            showHeader="true" title="Service Information">
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Risks__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Include_in_Dashboard__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Service__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Sector__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Alpha__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Jisc_directorate__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Beta__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" 
            showHeader="true" title="Progress Information">
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Level_of_Demand__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Feasibility__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Notes_on_current_progress__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_usefulness__c}"/-->
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" 
            title="System Information">
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.createdbyId}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.lastmodifiedbyId}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: I realized that even with jQuery I had to use a controller extension. Which means I can inplement this without jQuery as well. Let me know if you need to

Comment: Hi @salesforceMann it displays the following message. "XML document structures must start and end within the same entity." when I copy the second part of the code into the dev console, what should I change? and thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: I hope u added the /apex:page tag in the end